# Is it better to exit from a Function to cut-down on Activation Objects, than recursively or calling nested functions?

Tags: javascript, performance, function, optimization, activation

In JavaScript and other languages, I've heard about Activation Objects being created as you invoke a method / function. In order to optimize and maintain a good performance, it sounds like a developer should limit how many functions are being called.

Now if there's no way around it and you must call multiple methods, is it better to call one method after another, like this:

```
myFunc1();
myFunc2();
myFunc3();

// or...
var myFuncs = [myFunc1, myFunc2, myFunc3];
for(var a=0, aLen=myFuncs.length; a<aLen; a++) {
  myFuncs[a]();
}
```

OR, to nest them like this:

```
function myFunc1() {
  // Do something...
  myFunc2();
}

function myFunc2() {
  // Do Something else...
  myFunc3();
}

function myFunc3() {
  //Do one last thing.
}

//Start the execution of all 3 methods:
myFunc1();
```

I'm assuming it makes more sense to go with the 1st technique, since it comes back to the previous scope and releases the last Activation Object... but if someone could confirm this, 
I would really like to know!

Thanks

Comment: I believe calling the methods sequentially would have the best performance. There's overhead with the extra variables in the loop, and nesting the function calls will keep the Activation Object for each function alive until all of them have finished executing.

Comment: Structure the code in the most logical (and readable) manner. Don't nest the functions unless they actually rely on each other to do something in a specific order, e.g., if part way through `myFunc1()` it actually needs the results of `myFunc2()`. Worry about performance only if you actually notice a problem. (Note: there's nothing recursive in the examples you've shown.)

Comment: What would be your reason to use nested function calls ([CPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)) instead of the default linear, is there some async code involved?

Comment: @nnnnnn I realize there's no recursion in the example, but recursion is also a form of functions nested within eachother that could result a deep chain of Activation Objects.

Comment: @Bergi I was mostly just asking in general whichever is better for performance. For example, if you were coding some subroutines for a parsing / exporting tool (and those subroutines depended only on each other), would you rather call the methods separately one after an other / iterate them in an array, or would you nest them in each methods in order of execution? That was basically my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For information concerning Activation Objects, please refer to http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-2-variable-object/#more-546

This is not an optimization level concern however, as the concern you listed is an example of EXTREME pre-optimization and your time is not worth that type of investment.  And actually, the example you listed above, there is little to no savings when you are looking at Activation Objects alone.

As for proper use however,  I try to encapsulate as much as I can.  If a function doesn't have to go in the global scope, and can live within the scope of another function, then that's where it should be declared.

for example, for better scoping.

```
var f2 = function() {
}

var f1 = function() {
  f2()
}

// is not as nice as:

var f1 = function() {
  var f2 = function()

  f2()
}

// or even better.. 

var f1 = function() {
  function() {
  }()  ; execute
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> In order to optimize and maintain a good performance, it sounds like a developer should limit how many functions are being called.

Yes and no. Functions (or more generally, subroutines) are there to be called, and not doing so makes no sense. If you can make your code more DRY by introducing another function, do so.

The only place where not using them is reasonable are high-performance loops which run thousands of times doing little work, and function calls would add a *noticable* overhead. Do not try to [prematurely optimize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization)!

Also, there are some languages which handle recursion not well and where you will need to translate recursive function calls to loops, preventing stackoverflow exceptions. However, this is a rare case as well.

> is it better to call one method after another, or to nest them?

That depends, since the two techniques do different things. With #1, there are just 3 *independent* functions which are called after each other. In contrast, #2 defines functions that *always* call each other - you can't get `myFunc2` without `myFunc3`. Is that intended?

If it is, there's nothing wrong with this nesting. The two additional stack layers will not harm your performance.

Comment: Ok good to know. I'm not very familiar with the way JavaScript Interpreters / Engines frees-up memory after methods are completed. Is there one way that is more memory-friendly for the garbage collector to mark and discard (assuming JavaScript has some sort of GC handler)? ***PS. I realize 3 subroutines are too small to really measure a significant difference, but if the methods are iterated several hundreds times, and some tasks are more CPU expensive than others (in my case, I'm writing some JSFL scripts to automate Flash PNG exports), the technique #1 sounds more efficient.***

Answer (score 0):

Separation of responsibility:

```
private function myFunc1(): void
{

}

private function myFunc2(): void
{

}

private function myFunc3(): void
{

}

private function doAllFunc(): void
{
     myFunc1();
     myFunc2();
     myFunc3();
}
```

Comment: Gary, you do realize you're responding to a Javascript question, right? That looks like C/C++, not Javascript.

Comment: Agreed, but what language is that?

Comment: @RobertK - Oh please. jbabey It's ActionScript which Pierre (The question asker) is very familiar with since it's his primary language.

Comment: The question is asking about the performance of javascript, not how best to write his arbitrary example in a different language.

Comment: It's a good thing voting points don't convert to $ dollars. Some users takes reputation points way too seriously.
Thanks Gary, ***Separation of responsibility*** is a good aspect to keep in consideration. Sounds like it makes sense too: Easy code to read and understand = Easy code to execute. (But obviously, it may not be the fastest in every cases!)